# How to solve: As I am getting error percentage as 199 % using fortran in hpc?

Tags: fortran, hpc

```
   program EConstant
   include 'mpif.h'

   INTEGER n,ierr,lcv,rank,size,i
   DOUBLE PRECISION INTEGER factor, reduc 
   DOUBLE PRECISION INTEGER redat, redrl, repnt
   DOUBLE PRECISION actval, actdiff,erpnt
   DOUBLE PRECISION este, reldiff 


   integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

   call MPI_INIT(ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)                                                                        

                   l

   actval =  2.71828D0
   n=1000
   factor = 1.D0
   este = 0.D0
   DO lcv = rank, n, size
   DO i=1,lcv
   factor=factor*i
   END DO
c           factor = factor * lcv
            este = este + 1/factor
   END DO

   actdiff =  actval - este
   reldiff = actdiff/((actval+este)/2)
   erpnt = (actdiff/actval)*100 

   CALL MPI_REDUCE(este,reduc,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 & MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(actdiff,redat,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 & MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(reldiff,redrl,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 & MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(erpnt,repnt,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 & MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

  if(rank.eq.0)PRINT *,'The estimate of e is: ', reduc
  if(rank.eq.0)PRINT *,'Actual difference is: ', redat
  if(rank.eq.0)PRINT *,'Relative difference is: ', redrl
      if(rank.eq.0)PRINT *,'Error percentage (%) is: ', repnt
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
   end
```

I am getting error percentage (%) as: `199.20` what mistake am I doing ? My formula is

```
 error percentage = (actual difference/ actual value) *100  I am getting error percentage (%) as: `199.20` what mistake am I doing ? My formula is

 error percentage = (actual difference/ actual value) *100  I am getting error percentage (%) as: `199.20` what mistake am I doing ? My formula is

 error percentage = (actual difference/ actual value) *100  I am getting error percentage (%) as: `199.20` what mistake am I doing ? My formula is

 error percentage = (actual difference/ actual value) *100
```

Comment: my advice start by writing a non-mpi program, make sure it woks, then move on

Comment: looking closer, you should only call reduce once, on este. do the error calc only on thread zero after reduce

Answer (score 2):

A quick look suggests to me that you are carrying out an additive reduction on some measure of error and not correcting for the number of processes involved.  If, perhaps, one process measures an error of `100%` and a second process measures an error of `99.2%`, your program seems to add those together to come up with an error of `199.2%`.

But, as I say, I've only had a quick look.

Comment: You mean I should modify near the CALL_MPIReduce

Comment: No, I mean you should figure out what arithmetic you want to do and write code to implement it.  How do you calculate the error for the whole program from the errors computed by each process ?  Answer that, then code it up.